# Random Variable in Recurrence Function

Tags: random, difference-equations, stochastic-calculus

Following the [previously published question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26558/random-variates-in-recurrence-function), I'm looking for the solution of `RecurrenceTable` with explicit random variable. For example, something like

```
RecurrenceTable[{y[n + 1] == y[n] ξ[n] + Sqrt[y[n]] ξ[n]^2, 
ξ[n] == RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], y[1] == 1}, {y}, {n, 1, 10}]
```

Of cause, the random variable has to be updated at each step.

Update: The long-term goal is the implicit Milstein solution for stochastic differential equations (SDE), since the current Mathematica version (10.3) supports only explicit solutions.

Comment: This would be better described by some functions related to `RandomProcess`

Comment: Probably `FoldList` may be helpful, but I still do not understand how to implement it.

Comment: `NestList[{#, Sqrt[#]}.({#, #^2} & @ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]) &, 1, 10]` does the trick if you just want a list of numbers.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Thanks, but the `RecurrenceTable` solution below is more intuitive and, therefore, easier to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid pre-evaluation with the following definition

```
ξ[n_Integer] := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]

RecurrenceTable[{y[n + 1] == y[n] ξ[n] + Sqrt[y[n]] ξ[n]^2, 
  y[1] == 1}, {y}, {n, 1, 10}]
(* {{1}, {1.39139}, {2.06846}, {0.0207897}, {0.0337668}, {0.18907}, \
{-0.193236}, {0.315955 + 0.300832 I}, {0.742221 + 0.264775 I}, {0.775734 + 
   0.220208 I}} *)
```

See also [User-defined functions, numerical approximation, and NumericQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/4678).

*Note:* each evaluation of `ξ[n]` gives different value. You can avoid it with the following modifications

```
ClearAll[ξ]
ξ[n_Integer] := ξ[n] = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]

ClearAll[ξ]
rnd = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 10];
ξ[n_Integer] := rnd[[n]]
```